# Arquivo LaTeX corrompido

Tags: arquivo, latex, recuperação-de-erros

Eu utilizo o TexStudio (LaTeX) e hoje trabalhei o dia inteiro em um capítulo de minha tese.

Parei agora a noite e, quando voltei, coloquei para salvar mais uma vez antes de exportar para a nuvem e para o meu HD externo, mas, de repente, o computador apagou.

Liguei novamente, ele voltou, mas o meu capítulo que escrevi está com tamanho de 31 kb e aparece em branco. Não sei mais o que fazer, alguma sugestão para que eu não perca o meu trabalho?

Estou no Windows 8.1

Comment: Dá uma olhada na pasta "usuario\AppData\Local\Temp" e veja se tem algo familiar. Essas pastas são ocultas e vc deve habilitar exibição de itens ocultos no Win Explorer para poder ver.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [esse tópico no TeXExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/texstudio-autosave-recovery-question) o TexStudio não salva cópias temporárias do seu arquivo (Até existe esta opção mas por incrível que pareça ela é desabilitada por default), ou seja, você tem que apertar pra salvar regularmente.

Para ativá-la va em `Configure TexStudio -> Advanced Editor -> Special Options -> Auto Save All Files` (Veja que por padrão ela está em Never)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra opção, que inclusive eu usei no meu TCC, é utilizar o [ShareLatex](https://pt.sharelatex.com/). Tem também o [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) mas ele comprou o ShareLatex e agora são uma só empresa.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar. Eu perdi o trabalho de um dia mas ja iniciei e amanhã término. Eram apenas 10 páginas mas que com o PDF facilitou . Eu nso conhevia esta opção do TexStudio.Eu estou agora salvando direto na Pasta compartilhada no Google drive que mantém as alterações.  Obrigado a todos.